# I want to know the kusto query for getting the CPU consumption and memory usages by adf pipelines above threshold

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, azure-synapse, azure-monitor

Presently, I am using kusto query language to get the value of CPU consumption and memory utilized above a certain threshold. I have kept the scope as that adf in log analytics workspace. Whenever  I run some query I am getting no result, even when the pipeline gives considerable results for these parameters in the metrics section. I have gone through these sources for finding Kusto queries:
https://www.cloudsma.com/2018/07/cpu-processes-azure-log-analytics/
https://www.catapultsystems.com/blogs/creating-next-generation-queries-for-cpu-and-memory-kpis-in-log-analytics/
https://pixelrobots.co.uk/2019/06/monitor-your-servers-cpu-usage-using-azure-log-analytics/

And also tried the ones given as the sample queries in log analytics workspace.
Besides, on using "Perf" in the queries, an error is thrown stating that
"'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'Perf'". How do I get the results using kusto queries?

Comment: Have you enabled a performance counter for Linux/Windows? Refer: [Enable performance counter for Log analytics and execute KUSTO Query](http://www.dotnetpiper.com/2020/03/enable-performance-counter-for-log.html), [Performance Monitoring with Azure Monitor logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-oms-agent) and [Configure data collection for the Azure Monitor agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-collection-rule-azure-monitor-agent)

Comment: [Log queries with Performance records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-performance-counters#log-queries-with-performance-records)

Comment: Yes, I went through these documents, but I can't find any option for Advanced settings in LAW. Also, the "Perf" commands are throwing the same error as I mentioned before.